# ¿Hay alguna forma de cambiar la clase que ejecuta una función dependiendo de una variable?

Tags: c#, class

Mi idea es hacer varias clases dentro de otra clase más grande. La grande tiene una función sin código`A()`, y dentro de cada subclase, se escribe el código de esa función, pero con código diferente. Entonces mi pregunta es si se puede hacer que ese `A()`, se pueda ejecutar con diferentes clases dependiendo de una variable, por ejemplo:

```
public string selected_class;
public string display;
selected_class = Console.ReadLine();
display = obj(selected_class).A();
Console.WriteLine(display)
```

Siendo por ejemplo `obj(string class_imput);` una función que lee una string y devuelve un objeto.

PD: Soy novato en programación así que puede que no entienda lenguaje un poco técnico.

Comment: Dale una mirada primeramente al patrón de diseño de software "Strategy" (Estrategia), porque asi como planteas tu "necesidad", este patron soluciona esta problema [C# Strategy](https://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern). Comentanos si es lo que necesitas o el camino.

Comment: Sabes POO? sabes herencia? estas dando un claro ejemplo de clases hijas con metodos abstractos... lee sobre todo eso...

Comment: @gbianchi He estado leyendo sobre eso, y ahora mi código es más limpio, pero no soluciona el problema.

Comment: @JoseA.Fernandez Lo he estado mirando, y aunque no he entendido absolutamente nada, creo que no es lo que necesito, porque lo que necesito es ejecutar una misma función, pero dependiendo del objeto que el usuario seleccione.

Comment: herencia.. lo que estas nombrado es herencia...

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que debes asegurarte es que el objeto que vayas a crear contenga el método `A()`. Para lograr esto, bien puedes crear una [clase abstracta](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/abstract-and-sealed-classes-and-class-members), pero yo me iría por una [interfaz](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/interfaces):

```
namespace DummyConsole
{
    interface ICallable
    {
        string A();
    }
}
```

Luego, cada clase que vayas a considerar debe implementar dicha interfaz:

```
namespace DummyConsole
{
    class CallableTypeOne : ICallable
    {
        public string A()
        {
            return "This is Type One";
        }
    }

    class CallableTypeTwo : ICallable
    {
        public string A()
        {
            return "This is Type Two";
        }
    }

    class CallableTypeThree : ICallable
    {
        public string A()
        {
            return "This is Type Three";
        }
    }
}
```

Finalmente, lo que necesitas para poder usar tipos a través de nombres es la [Reflexión](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection), para lo cual necesitas el espacio de nombres `System.Reflection`, y para generar tipos dinámicamente necesitas el [activador](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.activator?view=net-6.0):

1. Necesitas obtener los tipos de tu ensamblado, para lo cual necesitas cargar la información del mismo usando su *namespace*:

   ```
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("DummyConsole");
   ```
2. Sobre la información del ensamblado, necesitas obtener el tipo de destino que quieres (usando nuevamente el *namespace* en el que se encuentra el tipo):

   ```
    string type = Console.ReadLine();
    Type t = assembly.GetType($"DummyConsole.CallableType{type}");
   ```
3. A través del `Activator`, crear la instancia del tipo de destino (recordando que implementará de la interfaz `ICallable` que definimos antes):

   ```
    ICallable obj = (ICallable)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
   ```

El código final te debería quedar algo así:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace DummyConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Define type (One, Two, Three): ");
            string type = Console.ReadLine();

            Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("DummyConsole");
            Type t = assembly.GetType($"DummyConsole.CallableType{type}");
            ICallable obj = (ICallable)Activator.CreateInstance(t);

            Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\"", obj.A());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Y obtendrías el siguiente resultado en la consola:

```plaintext
Define type (One, Two, Three): One
"This is Type One"
```

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias, me ha salvado de un switch case de 157 cases!
Sigo sin entenderlo pero me es muy útil, gracias!

Comment: @Zseb Me alegra que te sirva, pero efectivamente se me hace un problema muy complejo para un novato. Mejor estudia los conceptos antes de meterte en esta clase de líos. 