# ¿Hay alguna forma de editar una variable u otra dependiendo de un imput de usuario sin usar Switch Case?

Tags: c#, funciones, variables

Eso, que quiero poder editar una variable de varias, pero dependiendo del usuario. Esto se parece bastante a [esta otra pregunta mía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/510515/hay-alguna-forma-de-cambiar-la-clase-que-ejecuta-una-funci%C3%B3n-dependiendo-de-una).

Por ejemplo:

```
double A;
double B;
double C;

Console.WriteLine("Introduzca la variable a modificar");
char imput = Console.ReadKey();

Console.WriteLine("Introduzca el nuevo valor de la variable");
double value = Console.ReadKey().ToString();
```

Y después una función que cambie la variable dependiendo de `imput` a `value`. Que si hay alguna forma de hacerlo que no sea `switch imput {   case A:   A = value;   break;   ...etc`.

Comment: Quizás con `Reflection` o punteros puedas hacer algo.

Comment: También te puedo sugerir usar un diccionario.

Comment: porque? a un usuario, el nombre de las variables deberia no importarle (ni tiene porque saberlo...) si nos explicas que queres hacer, tal vez te podamos indicar el camino correcto...

Comment: @gbianchi No es el usuario, es que se lee de un archivo de texto, en formato `número/variable`.

Comment: Entonces no queres nada de esto, queres un diccionario o una clase particular.. todo depende si las variables son siemrpe las mismas o no.. estas tratando de solucionar algo que parece complejo (no tengo el escenario complejo) con algo terriblemente mas complejo...

Answer (score 0):

Crea un nuevo proyecto de cónsola, nómbralo "ReflexionCsharp" y prueba el siguiente código. Luego, adáptalo a tu gusto.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection; // Reflextion permitirá modificar las variables


namespace ReflexionCsharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MisVar mv = new MisVar(); // mv contendrá las variables
            Type ty = mv.GetType(); // obtengo el tipo de mv que...
            // ...permite llamar al método GetFields() y de donde
            // se obtiene el nombre de todas las vars.
            foreach (FieldInfo fi2 in ty.GetFields()) 
                Console.WriteLine(fi2.Name + " " + fi2.GetValue(mv).ToString());  // Muestra el nombre cada var. y su valor

            Console.WriteLine("Introduzca la variable a modificar");
            string imput = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Introduzca el nuevo valor de la variable");
            string s = Console.ReadLine(); // el nuevo valor en 's'

            try
            {
                // intentamos averiguar si el contenido de 's" es un 
                // número va a parar a 'value'
                if (double.TryParse(s, out double value))
                    // y a la variable 'imput' se le asigna el
                    // nuevo valor 'value'
                    ty.GetField(imput).SetValue(mv, value);
                else // lo mismo si 's' es una cadena (string):
                    ty.GetField(imput).SetValue(mv, s);
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }
            // recorrido de las variables mostrando el nuevo valor:
            foreach (FieldInfo fi2 in ty.GetFields())
                Console.WriteLine(fi2.Name + " " + fi2.GetValue(mv).ToString());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
class MisVar // Clase donde están las posibles variables a modificar
        {
            public double A=0;
            public double B=0;
            public double C=0;
            public string hola="hola";
            public MisVar()
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Creo que me sirve, pero no lo termino de entender para adaptarlo a mi gusto, si podrías añadir anotaciones tipo `//` al código, gracias.