# Cómo acceder a un objeto creado durante la ejecución, dependiendo del Imput del usuario, en otra clase en C#

Tags: c#, poo, objeto, clase, class

Cómo se puede acceder a una instancia de una clase creada en otro archivo/clase. He visto algunas formas, pero estoy empezando a programar, y la mayoría no las entiendo. Luego, es un poco diferente, porque no es que en una clase haya hecho un `Class class = new Class();` y ya está, es que he creado una función que crea instancias de una clase que depende de una variable:

---

Estas son las clases:

```
interface IObj
{
    string A();
}

public class ClassA : IObj
{
    string A()
    {
        return "Hola";
    }
}

public class ClassB : IObj
{
    string A()
    {
        return "Adiós";
    }
}
```

Y esta la función:

```
public static class ObjBuilder
{
    public static void DefineChamp(string args)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("Project1");
        Type t = assembly.GetType($"Project1.{args}");
        IObj obj = (IChamp)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    }
}
```

Esta función, de hecho, no la he creado yo, la he sacado de [esta otra pregunta mía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/510626/266781).

---

Ahora mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo hago para usar ese objeto? Sé que hay ya respuestas en internet, pero no he encontrado ninguna que yo entienda que se parezca a mi caso, en el que el objeto no se ha creado todavía.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este caso específico te recomiendo hacer lo siguiente:

```
public estática class ObjBuilder
{
   public estática IObj DefineChamp(string args)
   {
      Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("Project1");
      Type t = assembly.GetType($"Project1.{args}");
      return (IChamp)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
   }
}
```

Construimos un método que devuelve un tipo **IObj** y dentro de este método creamos el objeto deseado y al final lo devolvemos con la **instrucción return**.

Para hacer uso de este método hacemos:

```
var miObjeto = ObjBuilder.DefineChamp("parametro");
```

Y lo usamos como queramos.

Te recomiendo que te estudies los **patrones de diseño Inyección de Dependencias, y Factoria**, te van a ayudar mucho.

Comment: Vale, gracias, esto me sirve, pero me da otro problema, y es que si quiero usar ese mismo `miObjeto` en otra clase, como la importo?

Comment: Hablando de los patrones de diseño, que los he mirado un poco, sobre todo el Factoria (Que por cierto no he entendido absolutamente nada), me aparece la duda de que si los patrones de diseño son estructuras del lenguaje o son formas de programar creadas por los desarrolladores.

Comment: Por eso te dije que estudiara Inyección de dependencias, los patrones de diseño son buenas prácticas creadas por los desarrolladores para resolver tareas repetitivas, aprenderlos requiere tiempo y práctica, no vayas a pensar que los vas a entender en un día, su curva de aprendizaje no es baja, tienes que estudiar bastante para entenderlos y darte cuenta cuando debes usarlos